# How to click on link (submenu) in selenium webdriver using java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I got this Java code:

```
package com.ej.zob.modules;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;


public class Navigation {

public static WebDriver driver = null;
public void Execute(String Toplink,String Sublink, String ValidText){

//Actions a1 = new Actions(driver);
LaunchApplication.driver.findElement(By.linkText(Toplink)).click();
LaunchApplication.driver.findElement(By.linkText(Sublink)).click();
//LaunchApplication.driver.get(ValidText);
String Text =      LaunchApplication.driver.findElement(By.tagName("Body")).getText();
String CellText = LaunchApplication.driver.findElement(By.tagName("Div")).getText();
if(Text.contains(CellText))
{
    System.out.println(ValidText);
}
    else
    {
        System.out.print(false);
    }



  }
}
```

And this HTML code:

```
  ##  <a href="/ejagruti-ui/index.php/account/crudaccount"></a> ##
```

I am getting error

> Element not found

when selecting a value in the above html linktext. Do you know why is this happening?
Also I would like to know if I'm writing the if else statements as I should.

Comment: your submenu opens on parent menu hover?

Comment: Can you share the URL of AUT?

Comment: can you please tell what is the value in `Toplink` and `Sublink`?

Comment: http://www.server.com:90/ejagruti-ui/. this is my link and username:admin@zob.com ,password: password,select: English,and select:employee and then login.I want to select manage and then savings account.

Comment: values in toplink is "manage" and sublink "saving account"

Comment: @HelpingHands yess. see this link.

Comment: That link is not opening here m is that local server?

Comment: @AbNimkar I do not find any value in the HTML.....and linktext is the text within the anchor tag eg: `<a>LinkText</a>`..... and in the script which line is this error occuring?